# Resize html image in Weebly to available space

Tags: html, css, image, weebly

I am creating a site using Weebly where I have images that are links to other pages. In order to show that the images are links, I have put them in as embedded html and used some code to change the opacity when the mouse is hovering over them. I then put a link around this.

I can't seem to get the code to go in here, so here is a [jsbin of it](http://jsbin.com/natatanajo/edit?html,css,output)

I don't know very much HTML, so I got most of this from google searches. This works , but it will only ever display the image at it's native resolution, and Weebly will only give the HTML box a certain amount of space depending on the screen size. I want two of these images to be next to each other on the site, and evenly resize to fill the whole horizontal space, maintaining the same aspect ratio. I have looked at how to do this (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439310/scale-an-image-to-maximally-fit-available-space-and-center-it)) but I can't get any of it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css on your image11. Maybe your looking something like this one [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/9grvxbx1/3/)

```css
       .two_img {
    display: inline-flex;
    
  }
  
  .image11 {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
  border: 1px solid red; /*only for view both image are separete */
  }
  
  .image11:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  }
```

```html
<div class="two_img">
<a href="link">
 <img class="image11" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
</a>
<a href="link">
 <img class="image11" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a margin between each picture? The margin in the CSS is only above and below

Comment: Yes for instant you can separate them using  a{
      padding-left:5px;
    }

Comment: Where would I put the padding? I put it into the .image11{} section and it doesn't appear to do anything. I have no experience with html or css so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: nop <a> tag is different .don't worry.  go to the fiddle link I share on answer. look there is 4 part one for HTML, CSS, Javascript and other the last one is result. add this line to css part "a{ padding-left:5px; }"  then click run from left top corner. And take a look into result section. if you still don't get it I'm here for you. :)

Comment: I got it working, Thanks! Just wondering, what does the a in front of it do/mean?

Comment: a tag use for link if you remove the link and replace with anyother link like<a href="www.google.com"> .. then click on the image it will take you to google.com . Try it .. we use a tag for link up with other page or section we have.. please follow w3school.com and learn html  they provide you.. then you have understand which tag is use for what..

Comment: No not the <a>, what is the a in front of "a{padding}"

Comment: a tag contain the images see the code after image you close it.  We can use it for css like a class. It's better to create class inside a tag and use it on css section like other class. otherwise if you create a another section with a tag this will effect on that section two.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you place both images within a parent `<div>`, and further you can place each image within a `<div>` as well. Then style parent `<div>` to 100%.

```css
.image11 {
    float: left;
}

.image12,
.image11 {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
            transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.image {
    //CODE HERE FOR MARGIN/PADDING OF IMAGES
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesAcross">

    <div class="image">
        <a href="link">
            <img class="image11" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <a href="link">
            <img class="image12" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I used the answer above, but I'm sure your's works too. Thanks!