# How to fix IE stretching of PNGs?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using object-fit property to size all .PNG files and make them fit in a div. This looks great on Chrome but the .PNG files are stretched on Internet Explorer.

I have used a few methods found on SO but nothing seems to make it not stretch. I'm at a loss. Please help and keep in mind I am still learning please. Thanks!

```
<div class="container-fluid brand-logo-container">
    <div class="row container-fluid d-flex">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/eaw.png" alt="EAW" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/adamson.png" alt="Adamson 
                  Systems" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/electrovoice-logo.png" 
                  alt="Electro-Voice/>
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/avid-logo.png" alt="AVID"/>
            <img class="brand-logo" src="img/MIDAS.png" alt="Midas 
             Consoles"/>
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/yamaha.png" alt="Yamaha Pro Audio"/>
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/logo-camco.jpg" alt="Camco" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/labgruppen.png" alt="Lab Gruppen" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/shure.png" alt="Shure" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/sennheiser.png" alt="Sennheiser" />
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img//Telefunken.png" alt="Telefunken-Elektroakustik"/>
        <img class="brand-logo" src="img/Audio-technica.png" alt="Audio-Technica"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
.brand-logo {
    object-fit: scale-down;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 6vw;
}
```

```
.brand-logo-container {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: If you need to support IE you are probably best setting the height/width on the container and use a positioning or flex method to scale the image. These two questions may point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439310/scale-an-image-to-maximally-fit-available-space-and-center-it/28450112#28450112 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853749/max-width-of-img-inside-flexbox-doesnt-preserve-aspect-ratio/31856947#31856947.

Comment: you should change brand-logo width and height px instead of vw or vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), we can know that the object-fit CSS property not support IE browser.

As a workaround, you could display the image as a container background image, then, using the CSS background-size, background-repeat and background-position Property to resize the Image and set the position.

More details about CSS background property, please check the following link.

[CSS background Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Besides, you could also refer to this sample, and use Javascript to detect the browser, then reset the CSS style.